# how to add data attribute to the nearest class?

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="row code-container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="run-bar">
                <button class="run-btn btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-play">Run</button>
            </div>
            <form>
                <textarea class="HTMLcodeMirror">
                 </textarea>
             </form>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row code-container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="run-bar">
                <button class="run-btn btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-play">Run</button>
            </div>
            <form>
                <textarea class="HTMLcodeMirror">
                 </textarea>
             </form>                
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to add index attribute at every run-btn class based on `HTMLcodeMirror`. For example closest `run-btn` of first `HTMLcodeMirror` will belongs to data-index = 0. I am trying as follows:

```
$(".HTMLcodeMirror").each(function(index){

      $(this).closest('.code-container').find('.run-btn').data('index',index);

 });
```

But it is not working as expected. Any idea?

Comment: You're close. Your DOM traversal is fine but you need to modify your use of `.index()` so that the value is relative to the other `.run-btn` or `.HTMLcodeMirror` elements. Read the [docs on `.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to see how to do this.

Comment: @j08691 There's no `.index()`. He's using the `index` from `.each()`

Comment: Please describe why you think your script doesn't work, because it actually does: https://jsbin.com/sefukasare/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I should've said he *should* be using `.index()`